# 5v powered phone ring generator circuit

Tags: arduino, power, ac, transformer, telephone

I am trying to ring a phone bell with an Arduino. I have tried using a 12v motor controller (h-bridge), but I have an old bell, and that was barely enough to drive it, and I'd also like to use a single 5v wall wart to power the entire thing (logic board and bell).

I found several circuits that can be powered by 12v, expensive or hard to find ring generators (Black Magic and others), and one unit that seems like an ideal match, but a bit of an overkill, really: http://www.semiconductorstore.com/cart/pc/viewPrd.asp?idproduct=38816

So I'm looking for a schematic for something simpler that could make that bell ring off a 5v supply. As far as I understand it should be some kind of boost circuit and h-bridge combo, so I can control the frequency of the bell from firmware. But a fixed frequency bell that I can turn on and off will do as well.

Comment: https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/50

Comment: just use your  H bridge to drive  1:20 step-up transformer to create > 200Vpp from 12V loaded. you may need a lot of inductance to reduce primary current or AC couple with a large protected or bipolar cap.

Comment: Bruce Abbott, that seems to be what I need, how did I not find that post? Or did it get lost between the zillion tabs open? Anyways, parts are available, I'll try to build it tomorrow if I can get everything. Thanks!

Comment: There are probably [30 questions just like this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=doorbell), Please do some research before posting. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I once designed a circuit that replaced the old wind-up magneto generator in trackside telephones that was used at very remote railway level crossings. The phone, (when the button was pressed) basically rang a standard telephone bell many miles distant in a signalman's railway box. I believe that some may still be in use on some remote parts of the East Anglian railway network in the UK today. They were built to last and looked like this: -

[image]

The one above may have been a type with a DTMF auto-dialler but you wouldn't be able to tell the difference between an auto-dialler and an electro-magneto type. But, I digress.

The circuit was powered by 4x D type batteries producing nominally 6 volts DC but, conceivably it will work at 5 volts or 4 volts etc. It used a 25 Hz sinewave oscillator (probably a square wave relaxation oscillator with some post filtering to make it nominally sine wave ish) that fed a stereo bridge amplifier capable of delivering a few watts of power. This was back in 1988 so forgive me if I forget the part number of the amp.

The bridge output from the amp fed the secondary of a standard 230/6V AC mains transformer and the output from the transformer (the 230V winding) nominally produced about 100 volt RMS. It was adjusted to this value by adjusting the amplitude of the sinewave fed to the bridge amplifier.

It worked beautifully and now all that remains, for anyone reading this post, is to fill in the gaps. Sorry I don't have a schematic but it's not rocket science!

Answer (score 0):

[***This is how***](http://www.linear.com/docs/3225) it's done with SLIC's using +/-100Vdc.  We did similar in late 70's with bipolar in Project IDA.

[image]

Another Simple solution including 20Hz clock, adjust by 15%
Use a CD4060 with 20Hz and 1.25Hz to NAND gate for on off ring tone and Schmitt Nand for any clock that is a binary multiple of 20 Hz.

using +/-12V,5V from an ATX supply.
[image]